# 2 Wordpress Installations serving specific areas of each on one URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, dns, reverse-proxy, bitnami

I have 2 Wordpress installations on EC2 instances. Servers are running Bitnami Stacks on Ubuntu 18 and after a couple of days of trying to get this up and running I'm stuck.

Currently I have

```
 new.website.com (server 2)
 website.com (server 1)
```

`website.com` is the old website however it is still very much in use and has a huge amount of SEO value. `new.website.com` currently only has the homepage on. Due to the reletive instability of `website.com` we would like to simply display the new homepage of new.webiste.com when a user travels to `website.com` and, thereafter, display the backend of `website.com`. We want to do this to prevent any new code being merged with old etc.....

I'm aware that this can be achieved with simple redirects however we aren't wanting to display `new.website.com` to individuals whom visit the website and simple want them to see `website.com`.

I have explored multisite, network and reverse proxy options however cant manage to get this working and so any direction or help would be great.

In summary

Any traffic that hits - `website.com` - display new homepage from `server 2`
Thereafter - all other pages - display pages from `website.com` / `server 1`

The main element here is that whilst the user is accessing two servers we want them to see 1 URL of `website.com`

Answer (score 0):

Just use a full screen iFrame to display the new website inside the old website.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" height="100vh" width="100vw" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I did actually try this however I got some SAME ORIGIN and CORS issues. I'll look again at the option, thanks!

Comment: You have control over both domains so you can just change your CORS policy to enable the iframe

Comment: I've done this and the issue is now that the site then renders within the iframe continuously and navigates to pages of the new website within itself (as opposed to displaying the homepage and then, once navigating away, displaying the old sites pages). Thanks for you help in any case!

Comment: Ya that is because you have links on your new website homepage pointing to new pages, just point the links on your new website homepage to your old website pages